# Java/Generics: How do I define a generic value type?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a generic wrapper object whose value will be set at runtime. So:

```java
// wrapper type
class Value<T> {
   private String serializedValue;
   private T value;
}

// usage
class MyClass {
   private Value<Map<String, Object> mapValue;
   private Value<String> stringValue;
}
```

Basically, the `serializedValue` will be a `String` representation of the `value` field(like JSON string) and at runtime, I want to construct typed Java object from it. So for example, if `serializedValue` is `{"key":"value"}`, I want to construct a `Map<String, Object>` at runtime from that JSON(using a lib like Jackson) and set the `mapValue` field in a `MyClass` object. But I am not sure how to handle/store the generic type info so I can convert the serialized string to a Java object at runtime?

**Edit**: In this scenario, how would I implement below method,

```java
public  static <T> Value<T> deserialize(Value<T> toRender) {
    String serialized = toRender.getSerializedValue();
    T value = new ObjectMapper().readValue(serialized, <what do I put here?>);
    //...
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the type it if it's hardcoded?

Comment: Also, why not just _use_ Jackson, then? What benefit does rolling your own solution get you here?

Comment: @shmosel updated with an example of what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Where was method `Value.getTemplate` defined?  Can you add a `Value.getClazz` in that same object passed in as `toRender`?

Comment: @phatfingers Sorry, that's a typo - it should be `getSerializedValue`

Comment: You would need the class of T to deserialize that T type through reflection. However you can't get the type/class of T at runtime because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). As commented above you can just use a serialization library that already provides solution to this (and other) problems for serialization/deserialization. Or you can look at its source code to figure out how those libraries solve this problem (short answer: reflection and/or code gen).

Comment: Can you pass a `Class<T>` alongside (or through) `Value<T>`?